# Java RecursiveTask fork vs compute

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, java-7, fork-join

i have code of febunacci algorithm using RecursiveTask i found it in

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html

Code 1

```
public class Fibonacci extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
   final int n;
   public Fibonacci (int n) { this.n = n; }
   public Integer compute() {
     if (n <= 1)
        return n;
     Fibonacci  f1 = new Fibonacci(n - 1);
     f1.fork();
     Fibonacci  f2 = new Fibonacci(n - 2);
 return f2.compute() + f1.join();

   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
       ForkJoinPool fjpool = new ForkJoinPool();

        RecursiveTask task = new Fibonacci(30);
        long startTime1=System.currentTimeMillis();;
        Integer O=(Integer) fjpool.invoke(task);
        long endTime1 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration1 = (endTime1 - startTime1);
        System.out.println(duration1);

   }}
```

this code give executed in 83ms i modified it

Code 2

```
public class Fibonacci extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
   final int n;
   public Fibonacci (int n) { this.n = n; }
   public Integer compute() {
     if (n <= 1)
        return n;
     Fibonacci  f1 = new Fibonacci(n - 1);

     Fibonacci  f2 = new Fibonacci(n - 2);
 return f2.compute() + f1.compute();

   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
       ForkJoinPool fjpool = new ForkJoinPool();

        RecursiveTask task = new Fibonacci(30);
        long startTime1=System.currentTimeMillis();;
        Integer O=(Integer) fjpool.invoke(task);
        long endTime1 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration1 = (endTime1 - startTime1);
        System.out.println(duration1);

   }}
```

Now this code executed in 20ms can someone explain me why the second is faster i read the documentation it said that fork excutes asynchronously then why it is running slower then using compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is likely to perform poorly because the smallest subtasks are too small to be worthwhile splitting up.

`RecursiveTask task = new Fibonacci(30);`

Instead, as is the case for nearly all fork/join applications, you'd pick some minimum granularity size (for example 30 here) for which you always sequentially solve rather than subdividing.

Remember, Fork/Join framework is huge when it comes to bigger data sets to parallelize.

Source

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Because +compute()  doesn't use a new thread from the pool, and it's not run in a pool managed thread.
You will see the parallelism benefits of +join() when there are many RecursiveTasks being invoked by the pool. then if there is waiting or block in the compute method, its thread will be used by other tasks. so there will be less threads.